# Single-value extended property set to a draft item is not available when it is sent

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have set a custom property to draft item as single value extension property via graph API. I was expecting the same to be available to corresponding sentitem resource after draft is sent. But unfortunately I see that the properties are not available in sent item after draft is sent.

Will single value extension properties persist even when an item moves from draft to sent item?

How can i set a custom property to a draft item and get the same property value in sent item using Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Email will save extension property when an item moves from draft to send box.

Because one email have only one GUID.

You could create extension refer to these link:

[Create open extension](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension)

[Get open extension](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/opentypeextension_get)